# Как проверить, загрузил ли браузер страницу? QtWebEngine PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qwebengineview

У меня есть форма с `QLineEdit` и `QWebEngineView`.
Пользователь может ввести в строку любой текст, который предположительно должен являться адресом страницы и заставить браузер грузить страницу с этим адресом.

Как проверить, загрузилась ли страница или нет в коде?

Comment: я ответил на ваш вопрос ?

Answer (score 1):

> void QWebEngineView::loadFinished(bool ok)
>
> Этот сигнал выдается, когда загрузка страницы завершена. ok покажет, была ли загрузка успешной или произошла ошибка.

Comment: @Дмитрий-Лорез я ответил на ваш вопрос ?